# make code atomic for debugger

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

is there any way to make code for studio debugger atomic? e.g.

```
#magic(atomarize) :D
for(int i=0;i<100;++i)
{
  //actions
}

// other statements
```

so when debugger comes to the for statement, it doesn't show how it's executed (it executes internally) and at once goes to the other statement

Comment: You mean, aside from just setting your breakpoint after that line?

Answer (score 3):

You could put the code in a separate method and apply a [`[DebuggerStepThrough]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerstepthroughattribute.aspx) attribute to it.

Comment: thank you, but code in a separate method is not the same as the inline code

Comment: I understand, but you can't achieve this without introducing a separate method.

Comment: may some add-on has necessary functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget in gui debuggers like Visual Studio you have a "run to cursor" option - so you can set your cursor after the loop and then run straight past it.

Comment: it's just a question of efficiency, if code block is enough big and frequently debugged it is harassing every time to use run to cursor option